# How can I handle these checkboxes correctly? Code below, I tried many variants

Tags: javascript

I am trying to mark a label that is wrapping around the paragraph and invisible checkbox.
I would like to change only that label style, thats child input is checked/anything I probably don't have idea about yet.

```
let optionChecks = document.querySelectorAll('.option-checkbox');
optionChecks = Array.from(optionChecks);

optionChecks.forEach(check => {
    check.addEventListener('change', e => {
        if(e.target === e.currentTarget){
            check.parentElement.classList.remove('option-unchecked');
            check.parentElement.classList.add('option-checked');
            check.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('text-unchecked');
            check.nextElementSibling.classList.add('text-checked');

            
        }
        else {
            check.parentElement.classList.remove('option-checked');
            check.parentElement.classList.add('option-unchecked');
            check.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('text-checked');
            check.nextElementSibling.classList.add('text-unchecked');
        }
    })
})
```

I'm not expecting a solution to copy :D I would like to get some hint or something to search along on myself. Challenge me ! :D

Comment: You can check whether `check` is checked or not by `check.checked`

Comment: Thanks, thats one of solutions I've been trying to implement at beginning, but even after I check another radio input (i know it switches its "checked" attr) the labels style still remains as if the radio input is checked. Thats the UI problem :D

Comment: Is It Knockout.js?

Comment: It is vanilla JS. I already solve it myself while my senior dev friend was reading my code. Solution for further use below :)

Answer (score 0):

At first I want to thank for your generosity with my first question here. At second I would like to share my solution that I finally figured out so I could feel like a king for about a minute. Here it is :)

```
const optionChecks = document.querySelectorAll('.option-checkbox');

optionChecks.forEach(check => {
    check.addEventListener('change', e => {
        optionChecks.forEach(check => {
            check.parentElement.classList.remove('option-checked');
            check.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('text-checked');
            check.nextElementSibling.classList.add('text-unchecked')
        })
        e.currentTarget.parentElement.classList.add('option-checked');
        e.currentTarget.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('text-unchecked');
        e.currentTarget.nextElementSibling.classList.add('text-checked');
    })
})
```

For closer understanding:

- first I selected all my radio inputs by classname
- then gave it all an event listener 'onchange'
- then looped through them all again    to make sure that all of parents and nextsiblings has a default style
- then styled currentTarget parent and next sibling

and that's all, I hope this will help someone with similiar issue :)